# Any way to convert string with key = value format to dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a string like:

```
{
    c = type3;
    com = posss;
    g = 40111;
    m = "xxxx";
}
```

I need to parse it into dictionary. And each time the response keys are different. The expection is like:

```
let dictionary = ["c": "type3", "com": "posss", "g": "40111", "m": "xxxx"]
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: Why do you have that as a String? It seems to be the print of a `NSDictionary`. How did you get that? It's possible to get it back with `PropertyListSerialization` & `PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat`, BUT usually, if you have that data into your app, you made something wrong. You are using a `description` where you should pass the real value. So explain how you got it.

Comment: @Larme It's the server side response. I have no other options.

Comment: Are you sure? What's your Web call then?

Comment: "Why do you say I didn't do the research?" Because you didn't show any?

Comment: @Larme Our project has the old api used for many years. It's impossible to change it shortly as many clients rely on the api response. I could replace the "=" to ":" but the text might contains ":".

Comment: JSON and OpenStep format is not only ":" into "=". See the double quotes "missing" sometimes, etc. I gave a solution, and recommended to "fix" the issue upstream, that's all. It's still a value on SO to recommand and not only "respond" without hindsight.

Comment: @Larme yeah, totally agree. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, that's OpenStep format.

If you do:

```
let dictionary = ["c": "type3", "com": "posss", "g": "40111", "m": "xxxx"]
print("dictionary: \(dictionary as! NSDictionary)")
```

That's the format you get.
Basically, that's how are printed `NSArray`/`NSDictionary`, ie "Objective-C" Property Lists (inner call to `description` method)

Now, there is a way to get it back (after all, a *.pbxcodeproj* is in that format and Xcode has to read it back) with `PropertyListSerialization`:

```
let rawDataStr = """
{
    c = type3;
    com = posss;
    g = 40111;
   m = "xxxx";
}
"""

let rawData = Data(rawDataStr.utf8)
var format: PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat = .openStep
do {
    let serialized = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: rawData, options: [], format: &format)
    print(serialized) //By default, it's a NSDictionary, so you'll get the same output, note that the order of the item may change
    print(serialized as? [String: Any])
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Output:

```
$>{
    c = type3;
    com = posss;
    g = 40111;
    m = xxxx;
}
$>Optional(["com": posss, "c": type3, "m": xxxx, "g": 40111])
```

---

**# BUT #**,

How did you get that value? Usually, it means that someone gave you the `description` of a `NSDictionary` instead of giving you a reference to a `NSDictionary`. Once you clarify who's the culprit, you avoid that transformation, because you made `NSDictionary` to `NSString`, and you are doing back `NSString` to `NSDictionary` (might be overkill, no?)

Comment: Thanks. It's not. As I replied above It's really legacy issue thanks for your answer. I will try it.